# How to remove tint on icon in Material Button?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I want to have "Sign in with Google" button with white background and colored icon, but when I use this Google icon always gets tinted.

```
  <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign in with Google"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_google_colored"/>
```

How do I make icon not tinted?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I already found a solution, I just changed `iconTintMode` and iconTint color

```
  <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign in with Google"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_google_colored"
    app:iconTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:iconTintMode="add"/>
```

I am open to better solutions

Answer (score 47):

Use this and quit tint icon to show real color

```
  app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
  app:iconTint="@null"
```

Example

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/idGoogle"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
  app:iconTint="@null"/>
```

[icon with real color shows black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637591/icon-with-real-color-shows-black-background)

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't work on OutlinedButton. This solution works on OutlinedButton as well 

Answer (score 2):

You can also use white color as iconTint and use multiply as iconTintMode for colorful icons.

```
 app:iconTint="@color/white"
 app:iconTintMode="multiply"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me.  But after experimenting a lot I found this did the trick.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    />
```

It seems that the key is `android:background="#0000"`.  Don't know why @null didn't work, but this is what finally got that stupid color to go away.

Answer (score -1):

```
button.iconTint = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```