# icon with real color shows black background

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

Using the new theme Theme.MaterialComponents when placing an icon on a button shows me a black box, how can I place an icon with its real color?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/idGoogle"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
    app:iconTintMode="add"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/idGoogle"
  app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
  app:iconTint="@null"/>
```